# How Unit of work is able to give single transaction

Tags: entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

Can any one share me what is the significance of Unit Of Work.

I could not understance exact significant of unit of work for transaction

It would be really great if any one give example - how it is useful for transaction.

My Unit of work class is as follow:

```
     public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDataContext _dataContext;
    private Dictionary<string, object> _repositories;

    public UnitOfWork(IDataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity, TKey> GetRepository<TEntity, TKey>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
        {
            _repositories = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        string key = String.Format("{0}|{1}", typeof(TEntity).Name, typeof(TKey).Name);

        if (_repositories.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (IRepository<TEntity, TKey>)_repositories[key];
        }

        Type repositoryType = typeof(Repository<TEntity, TKey>);
        _repositories.Add(key, Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType, _dataContext));

        return (IRepository<TEntity, TKey>)_repositories[key];
    }
}
```

Thank You

Any example would be helpful.

Update:

```
     Suppose - 


                   _unitOfWork.GetRepository<ModelObject, int>().Update(MOdelObject);
                   _unitOfWork.GetRepository<ModelObject, int>().Delete(MOdelObject);
```

If any problem occur into second statement then , will it rollback for first statement ?

Can you please give some example as above .. i could not understand how it works.

Comment: There are pretty concise definitions of a "unit of work" readily available online: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html  Is there something specific you don't understand about it?

Comment: Updated question with some example detail.

Answer (score 0):

> If any problem occur into second statement then , will it rollback for first statement ?

Correct.  You can in fact test this to see exactly what it's doing.  I suggest opening a profiler on the database and monitoring the commands it receives from the application while forcing failures within the application.  This will show you what actually gets sent to the database and when.

You commit your unit of work here:

```
public int SaveChanges()
{
    return _dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

So until `SaveChanges()` is invoked on the unit of work, nothing is persisted to the database.  It's all maintained in-memory by the unit of work object.  So if you have these lines:

```
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<ModelObject, int>().Update(MOdelObject);
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<ModelObject, int>().Delete(MOdelObject);
```

Those changes won't persist to the database until you call this:

```
_unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is it due to below stuff where we check if repository instance is already created for some entity then retrieve else create new instance ? Then, when this will be release, I mean, the entity will be preserve into memory , when should we remove/dispose/detach  from Repository instance ?   `...       if (_repositories.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return (IRepository<TEntity, TKey>)_repositories[key];
            }

            Type repositoryType = typeof(Repository<TEntity, TKey>);
            _repositories.Add(key, Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType, _dataContext));`

Comment: @user3711357: I'm not really familiar with how you're creating your repositories here, it seems a little unnecessary to me.  But any repository which is created by means of that data context is going to be part of that data context's unit of work, I would imagine.